# Hide certain Magento attribute filters

Tags: magento, filter

I have some lines of PHP code that will prevent certain attribute filters to be shown within the layered navigation block (i.e. Price and Category). This way I need to add all the filters that I don't want to be shown by hand which takes a lot of time and isn't the best solution.

What I want is the filter attributes "Price" and "Category" to be shown and if the filtername is different, don't display that filter at all. This way the price and category filters are always displayed, and the other filters get hidden. I don't have to add all the filters by hand which I do not want to show up in the list.

My question is, what needs to change within the PHP code to make it work the way I just described?

```
    <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
    <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
    <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
    <?php if($_filter->getName() != "Price" AND $_filter->getName() != "Category"): ?>
    <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
    <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Are you wanting some filters to be shown for some categories but not others?  The way your question is phrased it sounds like you just want Price and Category as filterable layered attributes...in which case you'd just turn the 'Use in Layered Navigation' to NO for all other attributes via Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes

Comment: On the main product category pages all the filters of all the subcategories are shown. This way I get a huge list of filters wich I do not want. For these main category pages I just want "Price" and "Category" filter to be shown, or else the filters are a mess. There is no Magento option for this (hiding certain filters on certain pages).

Comment: Maybe will helpfull solution for Magento2
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/352441/9951

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I see.  Funnily enough I was working on something virtually identical yesterday and this works for me (I mean to the change to the IF statement);

```
<?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
    <?php if (Mage::helper('catalog')->__($_filter->getName()) == 'Price' || Mage::helper('catalog')->__($_filter->getName()) == 'Category'): ?>
            <dt><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Hopefully it will work for you too.

Comment: Thanks for your input! This code just hides the filters 'Price' and 'Category' for me. I want to find a way to only display these two filters and hide all the others.

Comment: Ah I see, I've changed the answer then - I've just reversed the conditional to == from != and changed && to ||

Comment: GREAT!!!! Thanks man! You've helped me alot with this one (and I think many more in the future)

Comment: Bad one what will have happen if i use another locale (not en_US)? You should check attribute name. Something like this: `if ($_filter->getAttributeModel()) { $attributeCode = $_filter->getAttributeModel()->getAttributeCode()} if ($attributeCode == 'price' || == $attributeCode == 'category'){ echo 'html';}`

Comment: @Serjio - yes I totally agree with you but I answered the OPs question and solved the problem in HIS store - not yours.

Comment: @rabmcnab it's a bad practice to check locale dependent strings. So i just want to write that

Comment: @Serjio - I need to learn best practice too if I'm doing things wrong, post a full alternative answer up that's not locale specific and the OP can change the marking to accept your answer if it's better.